# React not rendering correctly after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple form. You click an "Add Item" button and a textbox appears. On blur, the text entered in the textbox gets added to a state variable array. Click the "Add Item" button again, another textbox appears and so on.

For each textbox, there is also a "Remove Item" button. When this button is clicked, the current item is removed from the array and the current textbox is removed from the page.

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     items: []
   }
 }

 addItem() {
  this.setState({        
    items: [...this.state.items, []]
    }
  )
}

removeItem(index) {
  //var items = this.state.items;
  var items = [...this.state.items];

  items.splice(index, 1);

  this.setState({
    items: items
  })
}

changeItem(e, index) {
  var items = this.state.items;  

  items[index] = e.target.value;

  this.setState({
    items: items
  })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                <hr />
                <Row>
                    <Col column sm="8">
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        name="item"                                              
                        onBlur={(e) => this.changeItem(e, index)}
                      />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col column sm="8">
                      <Button
                        onClick={() => this.removeItem(index)}
                        variant="link"
                        size="sm">
                          Remove Item
                      </Button>                                                            
                    </Col>                              
                  </Row>         
              </React.Fragment>
            )
          })
        }
        <br />
          <Button
            onClick={(e) => this.addItem(e)}
            variant="outline-info">Add item
          </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem I have is, although the array is successfully modified in `removeItem(index)`, the textbox that gets removed from the page is always the last one added, not the one that should be removed. For example:

1. Click "Add Item", type: **aaa**   `items: ['aaa']`
2. Click "Add Item", type: **bbb**   `items: ['aaa', 'bbb']`
3. Click "Add Item", type: **ccc**   `items: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']`
4. Click "Remove Item" under **aaa**. Items gets successfully updated:    `items: ['bbb', 'ccc']`

The page should show a textbox with **bbb** and one with **ccc**. But it shows:

[image]

How can I remove the correct textbox from the page?

Comment: You should not be using `splice` in `removeItem` function as `splice` changes the array on which it is working on, so basically you changed the state without using setState function, which is not correct in React. Instead, you should create a new array with the same contents using `[...this.state.items]` and then use `splice` on that new array, and then use that new array to set the state.

Comment: ` items: [...this.state.items, []]`  the add items looks not correct. ` items: [...this.state.items, '']` . everything else looks fine

Comment: try to add a key to the text box

Comment: @RishabhGupta - I did create a new array in removeItem(). I didn't directly modify the state. If you meant to do that in addItem(), I tried that, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: @MineKrafter you used `var items = this.state.items;`, this does not create a new array, to create a new array you should use `var items = [...this.state.items];`. Since you are using `splice` on `items` - where `splice` modifies the existing array and does not give a new array, you should create `items` with `var items = [...this.state.items];`.

Comment: @RishabhGupta - I updated the code, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: In your map function `this.state.items.map((item, index) => {...})`, you are using `index` as the `key`, now it is supposed to be an unique identifier for a particular list item, but in your case it is not, it depends on the place at which it appears in the list. Suppose initially, you have 3 items `["one", "two", "three"]` (indexes you giving to react are [1,2,3]), and you removed the second one, then `this.state.items` will become `["one", "three"]` BUT, the indexes will be [1,2] - Therefore react will think that the third item is removed, and it will remove the third item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. Firstly, you are directly changing the `this.state` without using `this.setState()` in the `changeItem` function, I have changed it to `var items = [...this.state.items];`
2. You are using `index` as `key` for a list item, that you are rendering using the `this.state.items.map((item, index) => {...})` in `<React.Fragment key={index}>`. This `key` should be a unique identifier for the list item, usually, it is the unique `id` from the database. `Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity`. However, in your case, since you don't have unique ids for the items, I am creating those using `uuid` module. learn more about keys: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html and https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318
3. I have removed `column` attribute from the `Col` component, because it was giving some warning
4. Since, now I am adding a unique id to each list item, I have changed the structure of the `this.state.items` from `array of strings` to `array of objects, where each object has a id and data, where data is text`
5. you were using `Form.Control` component without using value prop. Suppose you added one list item, wrote something in the input, clicked on the `add item` button again. at this point, since you changed focus, the `onBlur` event would trigger, and your `this.state.items` would change accordingly, so far, so good. BUT now when it re-renders the whole thing again, it is going to re-render the `Form.Control` component, but without the `value` prop, this component will not know what data to show, hence it will render as empty field. Hence, I added `value` prop to this component
6. Since I added `value` prop in `Form.Control` component, react now demands that I add `onChange` event to the component, otherwise it will render as read-only input, hence I changed `onBlur` to `onChange` event. There is no need for `onBlur` to change the state value, when `onChange` is already there.

Here is the finished code:

```
import React from "react";
import { v4 } from 'uuid';
import { Button, Row, Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
  }

  addItem() {
    this.setState({
      items: [...this.state.items, {data: "", id: v4()}]
    });
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    console.log("dbg1", index);
    //var items = this.state.items;
    var items = [...this.state.items];

    items.splice(index, 1);

    this.setState({
      items: items
    });
  }

  changeItem(e, index) {
    console.log("dbg2", this.state.items);
    var items = [...this.state.items];

    items[index].data = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      items: items
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("dbg3", this.state.items);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <hr />
              <Row>
                <Col sm="8">
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    name="item"
                    value={item.data}
                    onChange={(e) => this.changeItem(e, index)}
                    // onBlur={(e) => this.changeItem(e, index)}
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col sm="8">
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => this.removeItem(index)}
                    variant="link"
                    size="sm"
                  >
                    Remove Item
                  </Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        <br />
        <Button onClick={(e) => this.addItem(e)} variant="outline-info">
          Add item
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Function needs to be bind too i believe.